# Finding a polyndrom in R

Tags: r

```
polindrome <- function(path_to_file){
  for(i in read.delim(path_to_file)){
    print(i)
   }
 }
```

polindrome("phrases.txt")

I have a text file "phrases.txt" (UTF-8 encoding). My task is to create a function that will load the entered data on call (1) and (2) return the file "phrases_updated.txt". The output of the function will be (3) a list with two elements a) a vector of all phrases that are a palindrome, b) a vector of all phrases that are not a palindrome. (4) The function also writes to the console the number of evaluated phrases, their average length (number of characters), average number of words and in percentages express how many of the input phrases is a palindrome (fill in a suitable description, eg the representation of the palindrome in the file is ...). etc., use arguments referring to the path to the input file and the output file as an argument to the function.

Comment: Homework questions are welcome! Please show what you've tried so far, what your thoughts are about your next step, and describe where you are stuck.

Comment: In general, when you need to write a function, I'd strongly suggest working out and debugging all the individual steps **not** in a function, then only when you have something that seems to work, put it in a function.

Comment: It's also usually good to start on simple cases. Give yourself a test vector `x <- c("no", "yay")` and see if you can get an answer working on that first.